# OpenLayers2: show polygon of images in mobile

Tags: openlayers-2, mobile, phonegap

I'm using Phonegap 2.6 and OpenLayers 2.12 for my mobile application.

**Feature:** 
in a panel (jQuery Mobile), I'm clicking in a checkbox and georeferenced images are displayed in the map that is already loaded. These images fits with that we call "blocks" in the map.

**With Firefox:**
usually, I'm working with Firefox at the beggining of developing stage. So the feature is working, the OpenLayers image is well created and displayed on the map.
[image: Working with Firefox]

**With the device:**
that doesn't work. Instead it draws a polygon around each image.
[image: Not working on device]

The method that provokes that is [`addLayers`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.addLayers)

Do you have any idea of what happens?
The only difference between the working and not working case, is that with the device my code is encapsulate with phonegap, but I have no clue why that should be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...I found the issue

When I test with the simulator, I can see question mark in these polygons.

So it just mean that openlayers can not find the image with the given path :)